# geopy.distance.great_circle not recognized

Tags: python, enthought, geopy

When I try to import great_circle from geopy using `from geopy.distance import great_circle`
 I get an error telling me that `great_circle` can not be imported.

I'm using enthought canopy for writing scripts.

How can I fix this?

All I really need is a package to calculate great circle distances for lat-lon coordinate pairs.  If you have a recommendation, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geopy package is not in [the Canopy / EPD repository](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/).

Rather, it is in the "Community" (PyPi mirror) repo (marked by the "PyPI" logo in the Package Manager), which contains 11,000 untested ("as is") packages. This repo is not maintained, and we do not test for nor necessarily provide dependencies for these packages. Its main purpose is for the use of some legacy customers. Our apologies for the unclarity and inconvenience.

We usually recommend installing non-Canopy packages using the methods described in this article:
"[Installing external packages into Canopy Python](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-external-packages-into-Canopy-Python)".

In many cases, all that is required is to *uninstall the package in the package manager* (if applicable), then to open a Canopy Command Prompt (or Canopy Terminal) from the Canopy Tools menu, and type:
`pip install <packagename>`

This should work fine for geopy, since it is pure Python.

Comment: Came across that article an hour ago.  Thank you very much.